# Как написать if/else sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Есть таблица injections

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть select запрос

мне нужно сделать так, что если date это предыдущий месяц то `estimate_usage_rate = usage_rate`
иначе просто `injections.estimate_usage_rate as estimate_usage_rate`

набросал пока такой псевдокод

```
IF(DATE_FORMAT(injections.date,'%Y-%m') == CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()), '-', EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NOW( ) ) -1, '%' )) THEN
            estimate_usage_rate = usage_rate
ELSE
      injections.estimate_usage_rate as estimate_usage_rate
END IF;
```

Comment: И кстати, что в вашей конструкции означает `injections.estimate_usage_rate as estimate_usage_rate` так именуют колонки в запросах, но в if/end_if это явно не уместно

Comment: ну само условие я бы пожалуй изобразил как `extract(year_month from injections.date)=extract(year_month from now()-interval 1 month)` но что такое тут AS, что оно должно сделать я не представляю

Comment: as не играет роли,
просто у меня запросы идут через алиасы

            production.avg_gas as avg_gas, injections.cost_centre,
и т.д @Mike

Comment: тут дело в том как переприсвоить при условии

Comment: Так, погодите, а в чем вопрос то, вы бы больший кусок кода привели. вы что то обмолвились о неком select, но тогда это запрос. А ваша конструкция if/end if в запросе не может быть написана, т.к. это язык хранимых процедур и он в MySQL отдельно используется от запросов. Если это внутри запроса, то там понятия 'присвоить' в принципе не существует и выбор делается либо оператором case when, либо либо _функцией if()

Comment: @Mike http://pastebin.com/apzEk40B

пример кода

Comment: ну так у вас там же case уже используются, вот по аналогии `case when extract..=eaxtract then usage_rate else injections.estimate_usage_rate end as estimate_usage_rate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select 
case 
 when MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) 
      AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW()) 
   then injections.usage_rate 
   else injections.estimate_usage_rate
 end as estimate_usage_rate
from injections`